# About Momentum Question

Tags: physics

I've $3F.r + 2F.2r - F . r = 6Fr$ momentum. is this momentum at clockwise or counter clockwise? And why? sorry for these questions because I'm new at here. Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: this is solution of a momentum question. But couldn't find clock wise or counter clockwise.

Comment: I just wonder is it clock wise or counter clock wise? and why?

Comment: Help me... please

Comment: If you want any further explanation you must give much more detail about the problem you are trying to solve. Not just one equation, but all the information about what each thing in the equation means and what larger problem this is supposed to solve. Also, to write the formulas so that people can understand them, start here: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Comment: Does anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Momentum is usually defined as
$$
M = r \times F
$$
where $M$, $r$ and $F$ are vectors and $\times$ is the [vector product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product).

$M$ is the resulting momentum vector, it is normal to the plane of a resulting movement, where a force $F$ acts on a point at a position given by the radial vector $r$.

[image: animation]

(Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torque))

Right hand rule: Your thumb points in the direction of the vector $M$, your fingers show the direction of the resulting movement.

[image: right hand rule]

(Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-hand_rule#A_rotating_body))

In the animation above you see the radial vector $r$ (red arrow), the attacking force $F$ (blue arrow), the resulting momentum $M$ (light blue arrow, pointing upwards=counter clockwise movement or pointing downwards=clockwise).

Further linear momentum $p$ (green arrow) and the angular momentum $L$ (light green arrow).

Comment: Is there a way with solve it as mathematic?

Comment: I just wonder is it clock wise or counter clock wise? and why?

Comment: Help  me please...

Comment: @Fahriye If the answer did not provide enough help already then you should not give it the green check mark.